# How to change direction of text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to create a 2-part circle using JS where 2 different sentences will be used to compile a whole circle.
I can't find out how to make the direction of the bottom sentence to be from left to right.
No matter what i do the bottom sentence starts from the right side of the circle and circles back to the left.

```js
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle,side){
                context.save();
                context.translate(centerX, centerY);
                context.rotate( -1 * angle / 2);
                context.rotate(-1 * (angle / str.length) / 2);
               
                for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
                    context.rotate(angle / str.length);
                    context.save();
                    context.translate(0, side * radius);
                    var char = str[n];
                    context.fillText(char, 0, 0);
                    context.restore();
                }
                context.restore();
}
        
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.dir = 'ltr';
  
  context.font = "14px Arial";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.direction = "ltr";
  
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height - 190;
  var angle = 3; // radians
  var radius = 180;
  var radius2 = 189;
  
  drawTextAlongArc(context, "Upper Text goes here", centerX, centerY, radius, angle, '-1');
  canvas.setAttribute('dir','ltr');
  drawTextAlongArc(context, "Bottom Text goes here", centerX, centerY, radius2, angle, '1');
};
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="550" dir="ltr"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve. I simply took what you already had and called [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) followed by [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) on the bottom string:

```js
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle, side) {
  context.save();
  context.translate(centerX, centerY);
  context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
  context.rotate(-1 * (angle / str.length) / 2);

  for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
    context.rotate(angle / str.length);
    context.save();
    context.translate(0, side * radius);
    var char = str[n];
    context.fillText(char, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
  }
  context.restore();
}

window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.dir = 'ltr';

  context.font = "14px Arial";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.direction = "ltr";

  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height - 190;
  var angle = 3; // radians
  var radius = 180;
  var radius2 = 189;

  drawTextAlongArc(context, "Upper Text goes here", centerX, centerY, radius, angle, '-1');
  canvas.setAttribute('dir', 'ltr');
  drawTextAlongArc(context, "Bottom Text goes here".split('').reverse(), centerX, centerY, radius2, angle, '1');
};
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="550" dir="ltr"></canvas>
```

Comment: That was the fastest anwer ever. i didn't even finish editing the question and i can't accept the answer as right because it needs 8 more minutes hahaha. Thank you

Comment: Yes I can't belive... Seems almost that he knows what you are looking for before you asking

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, the first solution I found is to reverse the string like this:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="550" dir="ltr"></canvas>  
<script>
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle,side){
                context.save();
                context.translate(centerX, centerY);
                context.rotate( -1 * angle / 2);
                context.rotate(-1 * (angle / str.length) / 2);
               
                for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
                    context.rotate(angle / str.length);
                    context.save();
                    context.translate(0, side * radius);
                    var char = str[n];
                    context.fillText(char, 0, 0);
                    context.restore();
                }
                context.restore();
}
        
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.dir = 'ltr';
  
  context.font = "14px Arial";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.direction = "ltr";
  
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height - 190;
  var angle = 3; // radians
  var radius = 180;
  var radius2 = 189;
  
  drawTextAlongArc(context, "Upper Text goes here", centerX, centerY, radius, angle, '-1');
  canvas.setAttribute('dir','ltr');
  let string = "Bottom Text goes here"
  var splitString = string.split("");
  var reverseArray = splitString.reverse(); 
  var joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
  drawTextAlongArc(context, joinArray, centerX, centerY, radius2, angle, '1');
};
</script>
```

Maybe is not the best solution but it works.